# How to stream a big zip file until end?

Tags: kotlin, grpc, grpc-java, mutiny

I am trying to stream a big zip file with `Multi` through **GRPC** service as follows:

```
@GrpcService
class HelloGrpcService : HelloGrpc {
    override fun source(request: Empty?): Multi<SourceResponse> {
        val file = File("/Users/developer/Downloads/Archive.zip")
        val res = SourceResponse.newBuilder().setData(ByteString.readFrom(file.inputStream())).build()
        return Multi.createFrom().item(res)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have received the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The JSON value of length 212507417 is too large and not supported.
```

My goal is to stream the file and not to send it once.
The question is how to stream a big file in GRPC?

Here is the proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.acme";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloGrpcProto";

package hello;


service HelloGrpc {
  rpc Source(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream SourceResponse) {}
}

message SourceResponse {
  bytes data = 1;
}
```

Comment: Presumably you're going to read a small chunk of the file and send it in a loop.  It might be easier if you used the Kotlin gRPC bindings.

Comment: yes, exactly that is my goal to read small chunk of data. I am using https://quarkus.io/ that is why I must use java binding.